# How do I send sms to a specific SMSC?

Tags: kannel, opensmppbox

On one server I have setup kannel with opensmppbox and everything works. On another server I have configred a SMSC for the opensmppbox and also a fake smsc. When I try and send message to opensmppbox (`curl "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?smsc=opensmppbox1&username=simple&password=simple123&from=100&to=2121&text=tere"`) message is sent but it is sent to the fake smsc not the opensmppbox smsc.

If I had to guess my config is flawed but because my experience with kannel is very limited I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
Here's the config:

group = core
admin-port = 13000
admin-password = test
admin-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
admin-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
smsbox-port = 13001
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"
dlr-storage = internal
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/mingiinfo.log"
log-level = 0

group = smsbox
smsbox-id = mysmsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
sendsms-port = 13013
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/mingi2info.log"
log-level = 0

group = sendsms-user
username = simple
password = simple123

group = smsc
smsc = fake
smsc-id = FAKE
port = 10000
log-level = 0

group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = opensmppbox1
allowed-prefix = "00"
host = test.server.com
port = 2346
smsc-username = "test"
smsc-password = testpw
system-type = "mysmsbox"
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
source-addr-ton = 5
source-addr-npi = 1
keepalive = 30
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsc_server2.log"
log-level = 0
interface-version = 34
validityperiod = 720
transceiver-mode = true
unified-prefix = "-,00"

group = smsbox-route
smsbox-id = mysmsbox
smsc-id = opensmppbox1

group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "hi how are you"
accepted-smsc = opensmppbox1
```

So my question is what do I have to change/fix in order to send a message to my opensmppbox that's running on the other server?

Answer (score 0):

TO force **SMSC** just add it to your URL API like `&smsc=opensmppbox1`

Check below link for your case

```
curl "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?smsc=opensmppbox1&username=simple&password=simple123&from=100&to=2121&text=tere&smsc=opensmppbox1"
```